# Why does my regex containing \d{1,} together with a negative lookahead still match, where it shouldn't?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a coordinate pair in a String using a Regex in Java. I explicitly want to exclude strings using negative lookahead.

to be matched:

```
558,228
558,228,
558,228,589
558,228,A,B,C
```

NOT to be matched:

```
558,228,<Text>
```

The Regex `^558,228(?!,<).*` does the job, while `^\d{1,},\d{1,}(?!,<).*` doesn't. It's the same regex with the metacharacter \d instead of values. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `\d{1,}` part in combination with the `.*` at the end.

In your case

```
558,228,<Text>
```

The `^\d{1,},\d{1,}(?!,<)` matches "`>558,22`" and the `.*` matches the rest "`8,<Text>`"

You can solve this using the possessive quanitifier `++`

```
^\d+,\d++(?!,<)(.*)
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufe3)

`\d++` is a seldom used possessive quantifier, which is here useful. `++` means match at least once as many as you can **and do not backtrack**. That means it will not give back the digits once it has found them.

[Java Quantifier tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Comment: Thanks for the online regex tester. This might help. Since the values are coordinates the amount of digits aren't fix. Any ideas how to keep that flexible?

Comment: @mamuesstack I found a solution for your problem!!! I updated my answer and the Regexr link.

Comment: I didn't know the '++' quantifier, thanks. Isn't {1,3} also greedy?

Comment: @mamuesstack Yes it is, but it tries always to match the complete expression, if this is not possible when it matches as many digits as possible, then it will backtrack, means give back the last digit and try to match the rest again.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the `.*` part at the end. It matches everything that wasn't matched earlier.
In combination with `\d{1,}`, which allows to match less than 3 digits, it will go like this:
`^\d{1,},\d{1,}(?!,<)` will match `558,22` and `.*` will match the remaining part `8,<Text>`.

Comment: Yes, the second \d{1,} will match 22 and the dots will match the rest.

Comment: Hey, you edited yours while I was working on my answer! ;) +1

Comment: @stema: I thought it was a bit very short. And I had the feeling, it wasn't the only reason ;-) Funny enough, we even used nearly the same wording!

Comment: I understand, thanks. The problem is that the digits are coordinates, so the length may vary. I assume that there isn't a quantifier "match most possible tokens"

Comment: @Daniel, I solved the problem! Have you ever used the possessive quantifier before? Its the first time its useful for me.

Comment: @stema: No, never. But then, I rarely use regex at all. Great find!